# PHP character sequence check function

Tags: php

How would I condense this php method to have less code yet still be readable and functional? What would you change in this code?

```
public function charCount($string, $max, $min) {

    $stringCount = strlen($string);

    if(isset($max) || isset($min)) {
        //Testing Max Chars
        if($stringCount > $max) {
            return 'String length: ' . $stringCount . "<br />
                    Max Chars: " . $max . "<br />
                    Error: To Long";


        }
        else if($stringCount < $min) {
            return 'String length: ' . $stringCount . "<br />
                        Min Chars: " . $max . "<br />
                        Error: To Short";
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: For one, shouldn't `Min Chars: " . $max . "<br />` be `$min` instead of `$max`?

Comment: Also "Too long" - there should be an extra "o" there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would choose between returning a boolean **or** a string, but not both, the reason is   to have an homogen interface.

However `false` could be used in case of error.

I'll go for something like this:

```
function charCount($string, $min = null, $max = null) {
    $length = strlen($string);

    $result = false;

    if ($max && $length > $max) {
        $result = sprintf('String length: <br />Max Chars: <br />Error: To Long', $length, $max);
    }

    if ($min && $length < $min) {
        $result = sprintf('String length: <br />Min Chars: <br />Error: To Short', $length, $min);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public function charCount($string, $max = false, $min = false) {

    $stringCount = strlen($string);

    if($max!==false && $stringCount > $max){
        return 'String length: ' . $stringCount . "<br />Max Chars: " . $max . "<br />Error: To Long";
    }

    if($min!==false && $stringCount < $min){
        return 'String length: ' . $stringCount . "<br />Min Chars: " . $min . "<br />Error: To Short";
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please always use `{` and `}`. I know you can write it like this but this code is _very_ sensitive to bugs (I speak from experience).

Answer (score 0):

```
public function charCount($string, $max, $min) {

$stringCount = strlen($string);

if(isset($max) || isset($min)) {
    $return_value = '';
    //Testing Max Chars
    if($stringCount > $max) {
        $return_value = 'String length: ' . $stringCount . "<br />
                Max Chars: " . $max . "<br />
                Error: Too Long";


    }
    else if($stringCount < $min) {
        $return_value = 'String length: ' . $stringCount . "<br />
                    Min Chars: " . $min . "<br />
                    Error: Too Short";
    }
    return $return_value;
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it like this:

```
public function charCount($string, $max = false, $min = false) {

    $stringCount = strlen($string);

    if (false !== $max && $stringCount > $max) {
        //Testing Max Chars
        return 'String length: ' . $stringCount . "<br />
                Max Chars: " . $max . "<br />
                Error: To Long";
    } else if (false !== $min && $stringCount < $min) {
        return 'String length: ' . $stringCount . "<br />
                    Min Chars: " . $max . "<br />
                    Error: To Short";
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Other than that I think it's fine. Readability should always take precedence over anything unless performance is *really* an issue. In this case, simplifying the if-else condition aids readability and incidentally also reduces the number of lines but I would argue the latter is not important. Also, default values.